# Angular conditional template

Tags: angular

Is this supposed to work?

The two `p` never appear in the browser window.

Console error messages suggest that the `#content` template is rendering before loading has finished.

If I hard-code the logic into the component that it's wrapping then it works, but of course I'd prefer not to have to copy all this in to every template.

```
<p>LOADING: {{ loader.isLoading }} </p>

<p *ngIf="loader.isLoading">LOADING+</p> 

<ng-container *ngIf="loader.isLoading; then loading else content">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
  <div class="loader">
    <div><span class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin fa-4x"></span></div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let m of loader.messages">{{m}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render templates with a condition in an `ng-container` you need to use :`[ngTemplateOutlet]`.

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="loader.isLoading ? loading : content">
</ng-container>
```

The rest, staying the same.

```
<ng-template #loading>
  <div class="loader">
    <div><span class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin fa-4x"></span></div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let m of loader.messages">{{m}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Why `*ngIf` is bad here? I guess problem in other place. Is `loader.isLoading` already `true` at init state?

Comment: it renders any template you provide with `then/else` condition. https://angular.io/api/core/ng-container

Comment: I _believe_ that I  _have_ done what is described in the documentation, but it doesn't work for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: Next problem: both tempaltes are rendered immediately, therefore the template that needs to wait for the loading to comlete causes lots of errors.